# Websphere CE issue in Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have downloaded the Websphere 2.1 App Server and verified that it works fine. I now wanted to use eclipse EE to manage it by adding the server to the server tab. Everything seems to work fine when going through the setup but when I go to start the server I get the error message:

ERROR [GBeanInstanceState] Error while starting; GBean is now in the FAILED state: abstractName="org.apache.geronimo.framework/j2ee-system/2.1.4/car?ServiceModule=org.apache.geronimo.framework/j2ee-system/2.1.4/car,j2eeType=AttributeStore,name=AttributeManager"
java.io.IOException: Unable to write manageable attribute files to directory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServerCommunityEdition/var/config
 at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.LocalAttributeManager.ensureParentDirectory(LocalAttributeManager.java:573)
 at org.apache.geronimo.system.configuration.LocalAttributeManager.load(LocalAttributeManager.java:327)
 ....

I was wondering if anyone had experience with this particular issue?

Comment: Problem self SOLVED: Seems the java IOException was simply because Eclipse did not have the correct privileges to write to the config/ directory. A simple sudo eclipse would suffice.

Comment: answer your own question and mark your answer as Best :)

Comment: @medopal - how would you go about answering your own question?

Comment: use the answering box below, add the answer from your comment, you can later choose is it as best answer

Comment: I am trying to do the same can help me with , what steps ur following and where to get web-spear application installer form , I wanna to try it out for mac actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem self SOLVED: Seems the java IOException was simply because Eclipse did not have the correct privileges to write to the config/ directory. A simple sudo eclipse would suffice.